# Count letter frequency in PDA

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory, pushdown-automaton

I'm trying to construct a PDA or a CFG that accepts all words where E is the most common letter. Cheese and tee would be in the language for example. I'm pretty sure this language is context free but I cannot seem to construct a PDA for it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but it would be a pretty fat grammar, for an alphabet with the three letters `{d, e, f}` it will look something like this:

> S-> ES | dJ | fK | E
>
> J -> SJ | fL | ES
>
> K -> SK | dL | ES
>
> L -> SL | ES
>
> E -> eE | e